# Sorting and searching coordinates for interpolation in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, search, vector

I need to make a nearest neighbour interpolation program.

My input would be the x, y and y coordinates of a point, for example x=.5, y=.3, z=.1

The output would be the velocity measured at the nearest point available. Since I have four vectors x, y, z and V, the program will look for the nearest node, lets say it is `x[5239], y[5239], z[5239]` (which corresponds to x=.501 y=.299 z=.1), and output `V[5239]`.

I was thinking of setting a couple of reference points (let's call them p and q). And my idea is to compute the distance of all the nodes with respect to to p and q. Then sort the vectors according to the node's distance to p and q (for that I would need to keep a reference of the original index, in order to be able to find `V[i]`). After that I could use a binary search, using the distance of the given point with respect to p and q to find the nearest node.

Another thing I found that could be useful would be hash tables. Which one would be more efficient if the number of elements in my vectors is ~96,000 and the number of interpolations I have to perform may be also that many.

How would I go about keeping an eye to the indexes (like the matlab sort function). Also what kind of sorting algorithm would you recommend in this case?

Thank you

Comment: I think you would be much better off using an [octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree).  Note that the "nearest neighbour" of a particular point might not be in the same cell - so you need to consider neighbouring cells.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index may also be a good source.

Comment: I would use your post to start coding and if there are errors then it can be looked at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Nearest neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) is a standard problem. Your are probably looking for a [cover tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree). The Wikipedia article itself is very short on detail, but it links to the original paper and an implementation on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you very much, that info was quite useful